# New User to Linux in general (Setting up a hardware firewall, needs interface config and ufw config help!)

Tags: networking, software-recommendation, firewall

I'm very new to this new environment (coming from Windows) and I need some help setting up a hardware firewall and web server combo. I already have my website set up and I would like some guidance on what I should do next for the firewall portion. Is there something I could use that I would not need to rebuild a machine to put on, such as Astaro? Ideally something I can `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu server guide has quite a good walkthrough of setting up a firewall:

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/firewall.html